# macro expansion in guile scheme

Tags: macros, scheme, guile, guix

In Guix there's a layer made of macros beautifying the creation and manipulation of srfi-9 records

The code is in guix/records.scm

The code is large and articulated

I thought to expand those macros to see their input and their output in order to have a feel of what they do

The thing is that even the standard vanilla srfi-9 records are macros around structures, in their own turn

So the macro expansion gives me a completely expanded code creating and manipulating structures.

I'd prefer to see the result of a single pass of macro expansion, to see what srfi-9 code the guix macros have produced

In Clojure there are `macroexpand` and `macroexpand-1`

`macroexpand-1` does a single pass of macro expansion and `macroexpand` calls `macroexpand-1` repeatedly until there are no more macors to expand in the forms being processed

You can see this [here](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/macroexpand-1)

Is there a similar option in Guile scheme ?

Am I missing any workflow trick, any tool, any library function or macro for dealing with this ?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, in the NEWS file there's this excerpt

> ** Removed function: `macroexpand-1'
>
> It is unclear how to implement `macroexpand-1' with syntax-case,
>   though PLT Scheme does prove that it is possible.

I don' t know what the problem is between macroexpand-1 and syntax-case and I don't know what Racket is doing about it

But at least now I know that macroexpand-1 has been explicitly removed

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple version of `macroexpand1`:

```
#lang racket

(define-syntax (expand1 stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_expand1 form)
     (syntax-case #'form ()
       [(id . more)
        (identifier? #'id)
        (let ([transformer (syntax-local-value #'id)])          
          (with-syntax ([expansion (transformer #'form)])
            #''expansion))]
       [_
        #''form])]))

(expand1 (or 1 2 3))
```

The output is:

```
'(let ((or-part 1)) (if or-part or-part (or 2 3)))
```

Note that Clojure's macro expansion algorithm is more simplistic than what's used in most Scheme implementation.

For an explanation `psyntax` aka portable syntax-case look in the book "Beautiful Code" for the chapter by Dybvig.

https://www.cs.indiana.edu/~dyb/pubs/bc-syntax-case.pdf

Comment: This isn't needed in Racket, which has `expand-once`, and it doesn't work in Guile.

Comment: See it as a follow up to the post by user1632812, not as an answer to OP.